# How can I stop vim from automatically entering visual mode when I click into the PuTTY window with my mouse?

Tags: vimrc, visual-mode, mouse, putty

*I suspect this is the same in vim as well, but fwiw I'm actually using nvim.*

For a long time I've used `set mouse=a` so I can choose to navigate my file with the mouse, if I so wish.

What I've never noticed today is that if I click into PuTTY with nvim open, is that this has the side effect of automatically entering visual mode.  Normally I don't click on PuTTY very much, but just alt-tab to it, but today I have a lot of windows open, and have connected two external screens, and I find myself clicking, and then having issues as I'm suddenly in visual mode when I don't expect to be.

If I remove `set mouse=a` (or do `set mouse-=a`) then this behaviour goes away, but I can no longer move the cursor within nvim with the mouse.

Any bright ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Just a guess but might be fixable with a putty setting. See settings in Window>Selection section, for example.

Comment: I can't really see anything there that would be relevant, and I've never changed (I think) any of those settings from stock.

Comment: Well, not changing settings isn't really relevant if you never clicked windows before...same as with neovim, no? BTW, you ought to try it with Vim and note the result as that could be a valuable data point.

Comment: Hard to say... trying to check, but when I run vim I can't get the mouse to work at all;  I type `:set mouse=a` and it makes no difference, clicking doesn't do anything.  Not sure what I'm missing there...

Comment: As for not changing settings - my point was I'm using the software in a very typical way - I don't feel I've done something unusual/peculiar, so thought this might be a common/known issue!

Comment: It sounds pretty strange. I've not heard of it before but a) it's been a long time since I used putty and b) I haven't quite reached omniscience yet. ;) Hopefully, someone here is familiar with the issue.

Comment: There are other possible values for mouse: I can’t remember them off the top of my head, but does mouse=n work?

Comment: I've not tried that, but I want the mouse to work in both normal, insert and visual mode.  So I believe I do need "a"!